How to force the string format (JSON) when creating dataframe
I am fighting with PySpark. I have a dictionary on Python called data, e.g.
{
    "key1": "xx:xx:xx",
    "key2": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "key9": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
    "key10": [
        {
            "key2": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ",
            "key3": "xxx",
            "key4": "xxxx",
            "key5": null,
            "key6": "xxxx",
            "key7": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
        }
    ],
    "key11": [],
    "key12": "x.xx",
    "key13": "xxxxxxxx",
    "key14": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxx"
}

I am trying to create a dataframe from it with the following code:
schema = StructType([
        StructField("key1", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key2", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key9", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key10", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key11", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key12", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key13", StringType(), True),
        StructField("key14", StringType(), True)
    ])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data, schema=schema)

The problem I am facing is that when creating the dataframe, the key10 value (which is a JSON string) is refactored. The column value looks refactored like this:
[
        {
            key2=xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ,
            key3=xxx,
            key4=xxxx,
            key5=null,
            key6=xxxx,
            key7=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
        }
]

The ':' are replaced with '='.... The key10 needs to be a generic string and not a MapType, ArrayType or StructType as the structure of the JSON may vary so I cant define the schema of key10 as any of those types.
I have tried using to_json() method and it works on the first level JSON keys, but 2nd, 3rd etc. JSON levels the values are refactored also, modifying ':' with '='.
I can not replace '=' with ':' when later reading the dataframe column as one of the values contains a base64 image that may contain '='.

For the items in Key10, do you know the all fields that can be in that struct?

No, as the keys may vary. In some cases key10 could have 5 subkeys and in other cases 7 for example, with different keys.

I have found a solution for this. It can be improved, as this is executed synchronously, which can lead to performance issues when you have lots of data to iterate through, but it is the only solution that worked for me.
Before creating the DataFrame, iterate through the nested dictionary and json.dump the value of the key 'key10' into a well-formatted string instead of using the to_json method of PySpark after creating the DataFrame.
data = [
   {
     "key1": "xx:xx:xx",
     "key2": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
     "key9": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
     "key10": [
         {
             "key2": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ",
             "key3": "xxx",
             "key4": "xxxx",
             "key5": null,
             "key6": "xxxx",
             "key7": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         }
     ],
     "key11": [],
     "key12": "x.xx",
     "key13": "xxxxxxxx",
     "key14": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxx"
   },
   {
     "key1": "xx:xx:xx",
     "key2": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
     "key9": "xxxxxxxxxxx",
     "key10": [
         {
             "key2": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xxZ",
             "key3": "xxx",
             "key4": "xxxx",
             "key5": null,
             "key6": "xxxx",
             "key7": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
         }
     ],
     "key11": [],
     "key12": "x.xx",
     "key13": "xxxxxxxx",
     "key14": "xxxx-xx-xxTxx:xx:xx.xxx"
   }
]

for item in data:
    item['key10'] = json.dumps(item['key10'])

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

